# Hide Authorization Token in Request Headers || ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, request-headers

I am using **axios** in my react project to fetch data from an API which is authenticated using a **token**. Now, I m able to get the data but the `when I inspect, the token is clearly visible in the Request Headers which is risky.`

Please suggest If there is a way to **abstract or hide** the token in the request headers to make it more secure.

Below the snippet.

```
const makeRequest = async () => { 
    const response = await axios.get(BACKEND_API_URL, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b' } });
    if (response.status === 200) { 
        // do something...
     }
    }
makeRequest()
```

[image]

Comment: Just use HTTPS.

Comment: @BrianThompson, In the production server as well which is HTTPS, the token is visible under `Request Headers`

Comment: Yes, its visible to you, but not visible to anyone between the client and server, which is what you really need to protect against.

Comment: i am confused , isnt the token meant to be visible to you the user but encrypted when some tries to intercept it?

Comment: "When I inspect, the token is clearly visible in the Request Headers which is risky." - Why is this risky? What kind of token is this? **Anything** on the client side is readable one way or another. Is this like a never expiring token with unlimited permissions? If so - the problem is with your token system, not the fact that its visible in the headers.